# Indenting lines of code in algorithm

Tags: indentation, algorithms

I am writting algorithm which has two stages. How can I indent code for stage one and for stage two?

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption*{my algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE \textbf{Stage one:} this is stage one
    \FORALL{i}
        \STATE do something
    \ENDFOR
    \STATE \textbf{Stage two:} this is stage two
    \STATE Update the trie: 
    \FORALL{j}
    \STATE do something
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the following example code I defined two new commands allowing you to change the indentation; simply enclose the desired fragment using `\bindent`, `\eindent`; the length `\myindent` controls the indent amount:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength\myindent
\setlength\myindent{2em}
\newcommand\bindent{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\myindent}
  \addtolength{\algorithmicindent}{\myindent}
}
\newcommand\eindent{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption*{my algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE \textbf{Stage one:} this is stage one
    \bindent
    \FORALL{i}
        \STATE do something
    \ENDFOR
    \eindent
    \STATE \textbf{Stage two:} this is stage two
    \bindent
    \STATE Update the trie: 
    \FORALL{j}
    \STATE do something
    \ENDFOR
    \eindent
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments to the code:

```
\newlength\myindent % define a new length \myindent
\setlength\myindent{6em} % assign the length 2em to \myindet
\newcommand\bindent{%
  \begingroup % starts a group (to keep changes local)
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\myindent} % set itemindent (algorithmic internally uses a list) to the value of \mylength
  \addtolength{\algorithmicindent}{\myindent} % adds \mylength to the default indentation used by algorithmic
}
\newcommand\eindent{\endgroup} % closes a group
```

Comment: this is perfect, just curious what does this line `\newlength\myindent` mean?

Comment: could you add some comment explaining what does each line do? thank you

Comment: @capoluca sure! I've updated my answer adding some comments.

Comment: I'm getting an error with your approach: `! You can't use 'the character 1' after \advance.
\ALG@cmd@2@algorithmicindent ->1
                                .5em
l.21         \bindent`

But @mahdiz solution worked

Comment: Thank you, it indeed generates indentation, but the line number of code also indents. How can I fix it? This answer can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333962/83288

Comment: This will **also indent the line number of the algorithm**!

Answer (score 27):

Define:

```
\algdef{SE}[SUBALG]{Indent}{EndIndent}{}{\algorithmicend\ }%
\algtext*{Indent}
\algtext*{EndIndent}
```

Then in the algorithmic block, write:

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Outside indent block
    \Indent
         \State Inside indent block
    \EndIndent
\end{algorithmic}
```

Comment: I want this to work but the definition throws an error.

Comment: Works for me without an error

Answer (score 13):

Problem of Gonzalo's answer is with numbering, as numbers are also indented.

Found better and also simpler solution for `\algorithmic`, the inbuild environment `ALC@g`

```
\begin{ALC@g}
   % Indent what you need
\end{ALC@g}
```

To compare it in same document

```
\newlength\myindent
\setlength\myindent{2em}
\newcommand\bindent{%
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\myindent}
    \addtolength{\algorithmicindent}{\myindent}
}
\newcommand\eindent{\endgroup}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textbf{Gonsalo's answer}
    \bindent
    \STATE First
    \STATE Second 
    \eindent
    \STATE \textbf{Proposed answer}

    \begin{ALC@g}
        \STATE First
        \STATE Second 
    \end{ALC@g}
    \STATE Something else
\end{algorithmic}
```

And result

[image: Test]

Of course you can include solution for bigger indent with `\addtolength` and `\setlength` inside my proposal.

Comment: Your answer is the best working one. Good, it avoids generating line number indentations. BTW, how can I set the indentation spaces? In your answer, it indents only one space.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to be flexible with the indentation size you can also quickly use `\hskip1.0em`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Foos}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State foo
        \State \hskip0.5em foo
        \State \hskip1.0em foo
        \State \hskip1.5em foo
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `algorithm2e` package, the answer is `\Indp` and `\Indm`. The first creates indent and the second creates negative indent, thus removes the previously created one. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110166/110934) for more details.

Comment: (In favor of those coming from Google): This answer is excellent for `algorithm2e`. Seek no more!