# Increase the indent in an algorithm

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indenting lines of code in algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69728/indenting-lines-of-code-in-algorithm)

This is my algorithm:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{My algo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE instruction 1
\STATE instruction 2
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Please, how can I increase the indent before instruction 1?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the term "alignat". Is it a synonym for "indent"?

Comment: @Mico yes that's it

Comment: I would like to specify the spacing myself because \indent generate a large spacing