# Implementing indent in algorithm environment

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using the algorithm environment in the `algorithm2e` package. What I want is to able to indent various portions. I tried `\indent` but that is doing me no good. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined

\KwData{Executor class}
\KwResult{Executes Main.java} 

    \indent \textbf{Begin} Executor class

    \indent call Main

    \indent \textbf{End} Executor class

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `\Indp` (the reverse effect can be achieved with `\Indm`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{Executor class}
\KwResult{Executes Main.java} 
\Indp\textbf{Begin} Executor class \\
call Main \\
\textbf{End} Executor class
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you should consider defining some structure to avoid manually writing `\textbf{Begin}`, `\textbf{End}`.

Comment: It's working perfectly! Thanks a ton. Should I be setting up some sort of macro for `\textbf{Begin}`?

Comment: @gekkostate yes. Perhaps one of the built-in mechanisms that the package offers for defining structures could help you.