# Indentation in algorithmic package when having multiple lines

Tags: indentation, algorithmic, pseudocode

I'm using algorithmic package and I've got this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function {BalanceCascade}{}
\State $i \leftarrow 0, f \leftarrow \sqrt[T-1]{\frac{\left | P \right |}{\left | N \right |}}$, some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long goes here, so this will create a few new lines
\EndFunction 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

And I've got the following result:
[image]
Is it there a way to indent the new lines to be under the start of the first one?

Update: If I do the solution proposed by @Bobyandbob the lines get too closer:
[image]
Theres no space between *lines* and *end function*.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! So the gap/indent in line 2 is should be smaller?

Comment: Hi @Bobyandbob - No, the gap/indent in line 3 and 4 (talking about real lines) should be bigger to start in the same point as lines 2.

Comment: Please  add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. MAybe related [Indenting lines of code in algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69733/124842)

Comment: You could add `\usepackage{varwidth}` and try `\State \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
      $i \leftarrow 0, f \leftarrow \sqrt[T-1]{\frac{\left | P \right |}{\left | N \right |}}$, some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long goes here, so this will create a few new lines
      \end{varwidth}` ... solution from [Include a line break in algorithmic while maintaining indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33995/124842)

Comment: @Bobyandbob if I do that, the lines get too closer, see the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I show what you had, then I show it in a `\parbox`, trying to use some horizontal `list` lengths to get the width right (it is close, but not quite right).  Finally, I again use a `\parbox`, but specify the width manually to match the right margin.

To get the proper vertical placement and spacing, I had to use the `[t]` option of `\parbox` and also end it with a `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function {BalanceCascade}{}
\State $i \leftarrow 0, f \leftarrow \sqrt[T-1]{\frac{\left | P \right |}{%
  \left | N \right |}}$, some very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very very very very long goes here, so this will create a 
  few new lines
\EndFunction 

\Function {BalanceCascade}{}
\State \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\labelsep-\labelwidth}{%
  $i \leftarrow 0, f \leftarrow \sqrt[T-1]{\frac{\left | P \right |}{%
  \left | N \right |}}$, some very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very very very very long goes here, so this will create a 
  few new lines\strut}
\EndFunction 

\Function {BalanceCascade}{}
\State \parbox[t]{313pt}{%
  $i \leftarrow 0, f \leftarrow \sqrt[T-1]{\frac{\left | P \right |}{%
  \left | N \right |}}$, some very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very very very very long goes here, so this will create a 
  few new lines\strut}
\EndFunction 
\end{algorithmic}

\noindent Here is the left margin
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Steven - do you know how to calculate the size to be passed to [t] for a documenta class \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}? If I use the code you give me, I will exceed the right margin!

Comment: @Néstor If I take my MWE and change `article` to `book`, it works out very similarly.  However, as I noted, I don't think my "calculation" of `\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\labelsep-\labelwidth` is precise.  The good news is, if your margins are different, I think you only have to manually figure out a number like `313pt` (in my example) once, and then use the same number throughout your document.